# POST "admin-ajax.php" 400 in WordPress Multisite User Frontend Pages

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, multisite

I'm trying to use AJAX in the user frontend pages from a plugin in WordPress Multisite but the **admin-ajax.php** generates **Bad Request 400** and always fails.

1. Developing WordPress Plugin - AJAX in admin pages working good
2. WordPress Multisite
3. Test on Site_1

This is a part of my code and the output, I just shorten it, There's a class to instantiate the AJAX actions and another one after it to include the JS file using wp_enqueue_scripts action ..

Anyway the JS file included correctly and console.log function displaying all JS data object as you see in the code below, BUT it always fails and **msg** argument print **Bad Request in statusText** .. What I missed??

```
/* == AJAX Class == */
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpmu_frontendpage', array( &$this, '_class_function' ) );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wpmu_frontendpage', array( &$this, '_class_function' ) );


/* 1. The JS file included correctly */
wp_register_script( 'wpmu/scripts/frontend/core', 'JS_FILE.js', 
    array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );

/* 2. Localize */
wp_localize_script( 'wpmu/scripts/frontend/core', 'wpmu_ajax', array (
    'ajax_url'  => esc_url( admin_url('admin-ajax.php') )
  )
);

/* 3. Enqueue */
wp_enqueue_script( 'wpmu/scripts/frontend/core' );


== JS FILE ==
(function ($) {
'use strict';
$.wpmu = $.wpmu || {};
$.wpmu.ajax_vars = {
    ajax_url: wpmu_ajax.ajax_url,
};
$(document).ready(function () {
    /* 1. DEBUG */
    console.log($.wpmu.ajax_vars);
    /* 2. DEBUG - OUTPUT */
    -- ajax_vars:
    --    ajax_url: "http://localwp.com:90/wpmu/SITE_1/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"

    /* ========= Main Code ======== */
    $(document.body).on('click', '#my-wrapper .submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var server_data = {
            action: 'wpmu_frontendpage',
        };

        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            async: true,
            url: $.wpmu.ajax_vars.ajax_url,
            data: server_data,

        }).done(function (response) {
            alert('success');
        }).fail(function (msg) {
            console.log( msg );
        });

        return false;

    });
});

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help others, I found the solution, That's because I made an IF condition check if not admin page and the {wp_ajax_} actions MUST triggered globally, I thought that it's good to instantiate the AJAX class when it needed in the frontend user pages only.

**-- Old Code -- WRONG**

```
if( ! is_admin() ) {
   /* Instantiate the AJAX class */
   add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpmu_frontendpage', array( &$this, '_class_function' ) );
   add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wpmu_frontendpage', array( &$this, '_class_function' ) );
}
```

**-- Fix**

```
/* Instantiate the AJAX class without NON-Admin pages condition */
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpmu_frontendpage', array( &$this, '_class_function' ) );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wpmu_frontendpage', array( &$this, '_class_function' )
```